# returning a sub-array of size n, assume the size of n is between 1 and bestTime.length, and return with the lowest sub arrays

Tags: java, arrays, junit

> int[] bestTime = {50, 73, 72, 75, 71, 56, 61, 60, 62, 68, 70, 50, 70};
>
> > assume if n = 6, expected return = {50, 50, 56, 60, 61, 62}

this is what i have so far, i know there are lots of mistakes. any suggestions is much appreciated.

```
public static int[] bestRun(int n) {
int[] best = bestTime[0];

for(int i = 0; i <= bestTime.length; i++ ) {
        if(bestTime[i] <= best) {
                best = bestTime[i];
                best++;
        } return best;
    }
    if(best.length == n) {
        return best;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Build an IntStream of your `bestTime` array, sort them, limit using `n`, convert to array and return:

```
public static int[] bestRun(int n) {
    return IntStream.of(bestTime).sorted().limit(n).toArray();
}
```

You can do the task also using classic for loops. But then you need to implement the sorting yourself. Something like below should give you a how this can be accomplished:

```
static int[] bestTime = {50, 73, 72, 75, 71, 56, 61, 60, 62, 68, 70, 50, 70};

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    int[] best = bestRun(6);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(best));
}

public static int[] bestRun(int n) {
    //copy your bestTime array
    int[] copy = new int[bestTime.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++){
        copy[i] = bestTime[i];
    }
    
    //sort copy
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {     
        for (int j = i+1; j < copy.length; j++) { 
           int temp = 0;
           if(copy[i] > copy[j]) {    
               temp = copy[i];    
               copy[i] = copy[j];    
               copy[j] = temp;    
           }     
        }     
    } 
    
    //fill your result array
    int[] result = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        result[i] = copy[i];
    }        
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to solve this without importing IntStream ?

Comment: for example using for loops and not importing any java libraries